# Filter and find documents which have more than one element in an array of objects which have same key value pair - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, filter

A sample collection

```
[
  {
    "_id":"id1",
    "usersArray":[
      {
        "name":"user1Name",
        "type":1
      },
      {
        "name":"user2Name",
        "type":1
      },
      {
        "name":"user3Name",
        "type":2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id":"id2",
    "usersArray":[
      {
        "name":"user4Name",
        "type":1
      },
      {
        "name":"user5Name",
        "type":3
      },
      {
        "name":"user6Name",
        "type":2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id":"id3",
    "usersArray":[
      {
        "name":"user7Name",
        "type":1
      },
      {
        "name":"user8Name",
        "type":1
      },
      {
        "name":"user9Name",
        "type":2
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

What I need is a filter that will return the documents with _id id1 and id3 since they have **more than 1** objects in usersArray which have key-value pairs `"type": 1`. It would be great if you could resolve this with just the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$expr` - Allow using aggregation operator.

   1.1. `$gt` - Filter the document with the result of *1.1.1* greater than 1.

   1.1.1. `$size` - Get the size of the result *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. `$filter` - Filter the document(s) with `type: 1` in `usersArray`.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$usersArray",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.type",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      1
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PlObvxDt7cA)

---

In case `usersArray` is possibly null or not array, then you need to check the `usersArray` is an array, else assign an empty array via `$cond` and `$isArray`.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $isArray: "$usersArray"
                },
                then: "$usersArray",
                else: []
              }
            },
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.type",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      1
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (With check array)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1nWNfG_KYSd)

Comment: Is there a way to bypass documents that does not have usersArray field or it is null or having a different type than array? Currently this query is throwing error `input to $filter must be an array not string`

Comment: Hi sorry for late, I had added answer for checking `usersArray` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- make it set(`$union` with empty), get the $size
- get the original $size
- if set size < original size => it contained duplicated type

*this is a way to do it not for `type:1` duplicate only, this keeps documents that dont have duplicate same types, i am not sure what you need. (for example if `type:2` is duplicated document wont pass the filter also)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6298c067853f039c69b0f913)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$expr": 
     {"$lt": 
       [{"$size": {"$setUnion": ["$usersArray.type", []]}},
        {"$size": "$usersArray.type"}]}}}])
```